# Angular 2 - Can't resolve all parameters for LoginService

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a small issue that seems to be about dependencies injection. I've made myself an HttpClient service to authenticate my calls and I've declared it this way :

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpClient {
  constructor(private _http: Http, private _cookieService: CookieService, private _loginService: LoginService) {}
  ...
}
```

The error comes from this file with the LoginService injection (if I remove it, the app works). Note that I already have the LoginService injected in some other files and there's no trouble, and it is also correctly imported.

The error is this one :

> zone.min.js:1 Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for LoginService: (?, CookieService)

If it can help, here's how LoginService is declared :

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  constructor (private _apiEndpoint: ApiEndpoint, private _cookieService: CookieService) {}
  ...
}
```

and they're all in the app providers in app.module.ts :

```
providers: [
    ApiEndpoint,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    CookieService,
    LoginService,
    HttpClient,
    provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}),
    provide(ExceptionHandler, {useClass: MyExceptionHandler})
],
```

Has anyone an idea ? Thanks !

Comment: have you imported properly `ApiEndpoint` in your loginService ?

Comment: maybe the CookieService has a dependence that isn't injected?

Comment: The thing is that both ApiEndpoint and CookieService are injected in some other constructors and I never had troubles, all imports are supposed to be alright yeah

Comment: 1. What are the dependencies of the `CookieService`? 2. What are the dependencies of the `ApiEndpoint`?

Comment: Well for the `CookieService` there's none as it's from the angular2-cookie library. For ApiEndpoint, I have `constructor (private _http: HttpClient) {}`

Comment: You have a circular dependency when you add `LoginService`. It depends on `ApiEndpoint`, which depends on `HttpClient`

Comment: Hm maybe that's the problem, gotta try to find a solution

Answer (score 2):

Like mentioned in comments, the problem is a circular dependency. Design seems to be fine up until you say that HttpClient needs LoginService. Your dependency chain looks like this:

LoginService > ApiEndpoint > HttpClient -x- LoginService

- LoginService needs ApiEndpoint makes sense
- ApiEndpoint needs HttpClient makes sense
- HttpClient should not depend on LoginService

You need to find what HttpClient needs inside LoginService and take it out into its own service. You're dependencies should look something like this.

```
 @Injectable()
 export class LoginService {
   constructor(apiEndpoint: ApiEndpoint, newServiceWithCommonStuff: NewServiceWithCommonStuff) {}
 }

 @Injectable()
 export class ApiEndpoint {
   constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) {}
 }

 @Injectable()
 export class NewServiceWithCommonStuff {

 }

 @Injectable()
 export class HttpClient {
   constructor(newServiceWithCommonStuff: NewServiceWithCommonStuff) {}
 }
```

- LoginService > ApiEndpoint > HttpClient
- LoginService > NewServiceWithCommonStuff
- HttpClient > NewServiceWithCommonStuff